# Achieving authentication flow similar to SAML in OIDC

Tags: oauth-2.0, saml, okta, openid-connect

Say, we have a SPA that relies on APIs from my application. Both the SPA and the REST API are hosted on same server. Now I'm using IDP initiated Federated SSO based on SAML.

I clearly know the parties involved and how the trust is established.

1. For each customer with whom we need to integrate, first get the configuration details like IDP ID, Digital Certificate and share details like SAML ACS URL from my web application side.
2. On customer end, they add my application as a Relying Party with the SAML ACS URL we provide.
3. Users are authenticated at IDP and then the SAMLResponse is posted to my ACS URL.
4. We can validate this SAMLResponse and also observe the NameID to identify the user and proceed to give access to the APIs on my server.

Now, assuming the IDP on the customer side is a OIDC compliant service like Okta, can I achieve a similar authentication flow by making some changes on my server side as well. Looks like it should be possible but I'm not able to piece the full picture together.

Based on my understanding of OIDC it looks like

1. The SPA is the Client
2. My Server exposing the REST APIs is the Resource Server.
3. Customer's IDP(Okta) is the Authorization server.

From the articles I've read it looks like the SPA should first make calls to Authorization Server to get the access token and then use this access token to make the call to userInfo API on Resource Server. Then it looks like point #2 above that my server is resource server is wrong. Customer's IDP should be both Authorization server and Resource Server as well?

In that case where does the my server fit in the whole OIDC flow?

How is the trust established between Okta(customer's IDP) and my server?

Is it possible to achieve a flow that is equivalent to IDP Initiated Fed SSO flow(using SAML) in OIDC?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Openid Connect implicit grant type (and response_mode=form_post) to achieve the similar user experience like SAML HTTP Post binding. If your IdP does not support form_post, the tokens will be returned as fragment and stay in browser, and you will need code to fetch token from browser.